# Exercise in §12 (The Peano Axioms) in Naive Set Theory by Paul Halmos.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Statement:**

Given any natural number $n \in w$, prove that for every subset $E$ such that $\emptyset \neq E \subset n$ it holds that $\exists k \in E, \forall m \in E, m \neq k : k \in m$.

[image: Problem definition as in original]
I've come up with the following proof but I'm not sure it is correct.

---

**Proof (by Induction):**

1. For $0 \in w$ the statement holds vacuously.
2. Assume it holds for $n \in w$ and show $\emptyset \neq E \subset n^+ \text{ with } n^+ = n \cup \{n\}$, then $\exists k \in E, \forall m \in E, m \neq k : k \in m$.

For the latter we consider two cases.

In the first case $n \not \in E$ , then it must follow that $E \subset n \subset n^+$. Thus the desired $k$ exists by the induction hypothesis.

In the second case $n \in E$. Then it holds that $E \setminus \{n\} \subset n \subset n^+$. Here, again by the induction hypothesis, there is such $k$ that would satisfy $m \in E \setminus \{n\} \subset n, m \neq k: k \in m$. Lastly we check the left-out scenario $m = n$ (bearing in mind that $k \neq n)$. In this scenario however, since $k \in n^+$ and $k \neq n$, so it must hold due to $n^+ = n \cup \{n\}$ that $k \in n$.

Comment: Are you sure the statement doesn't say $\forall m \in E, m \neq k : m \in k$?

Comment: No, it's $k \in m$.

Comment: Huh, that's really bizarre. You can make the statement much more general in that case - you can prove it for all $E \neq \emptyset$ (not just for bounded $E$). The correct way to set up the induction is "For all $n \in \omega$, for all $E \subseteq \omega$ such that $n \in E$, $\exists k \in E \forall m \in E (m \neq k \to k \in m)$". You then proceed by strong induction.

Comment: See the description as in the book (question edited).

Comment: @MarkSaving - I think the boundedness was just a side affect of how they chose to require $E$ to be a set of *natural numbers*. Why $E \subset \omega$ wasn't used, I have no idea.

Comment: @CCCP - In your second case, you have to consider the case $E = \{n\}$. Trivial, but the argument you gave fails in this case.

Comment: You're right about that. Good catch. If you formulate your comment into an answer I will accept.